# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2026 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, anaconda

After switching from homebrew python to anaconda python, code that worked previously, now gets the following error:

> `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed`

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host = "localhost",
  user = "root",
  passwd = "123456root",
  database = "tourists"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE tourists")

#mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE clients(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT                PRIMARY KEY,firstname VARCHAR(255), lastname VARCHAR(225), year VARCHAR(5),   room VARCHAR(2))")

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE clients ADD COLUMN telefon")

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE clients ADD COLUMN parere")

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE clients ADD COLUMN localitate"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that mysql connector in anaconda is having some compatibility issues with openssl. The solution is to downgrade openssl.

```
conda install openssl=1.0.2p
```

See this thread for more information:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10646

Answer (score 0):

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "password",use_pure=True)
print(conn)
if(conn):
    print("Connection successful")
else:
    print("Connection unsuccessful")
```

Comment: If you are getting this error (2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed) . use  use_pure=True in your connection query. To avoid this Error